# Hide notification icon from status bar android

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-statusbar

I have an issue with hiding the notification icon in the status bar from a service notification.

Here what I did:
I set the notification priority to min, make them silents

```
   NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"test");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notif);
    builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
    builder.setContentText(profile.mName);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setNotificationSilent();
    builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN);
```

In the channel, I set the priority to min too but I still see the notification icon in the status bar

```
      NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(id, getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.app_name), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN);
        channel.setSound(null, null);
        channel.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN);
        channel.enableVibration(false);
```

[image: App icon I need to remove]

Comment: Are you canceling the notification?

Comment: No I don't, I think if I canceled the notification it will destroy the service

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the thing I can understand that you first tried with priority or importance high with notification channel. According to documentation once notification channel created then it cannot be updated by changing code. If you want to apply new changes like priority or importance low like you did in code, then you need to `clear app cache` or `uninstall app` and then re-install again.This will apply new notification channel changes to your app.

Comment: I tried to uninstall and install the app again but it didn't fix the issue

Comment: According to documentation, Low: No sound and does not appear in the status bar.

Comment: Please also have a look on [this](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#Priority).

Comment: Thank you, I have checked and uninstalled the app but I still see the notification icon in the statusbar